# sql query for a certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I have a table like:

```
empId empSalary empDept
1   45000   IT
2   40000   IT
3   50000   SALES
4   60000   SALES
5   75000   IT
6   80000   IT
7   25000   OPS
8   30000   OPS
9   55000   MARKETING
10  60000   MARKETING
```

I have to write a query as:

```
select empId where empSalary  > avg(empSalary) for each  empDept
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You should decide what database you are using and tag your questions appropriately.  MySQL and SQL Server are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.empId, e.empSalary, e.empDept  
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN (SELECT e1.empDept, AVG(e1.empSalary) empSalary 
            FROM employee e1 
            GROUP BY e1.empDept
           ) a ON e.empDept = a.empDept AND e.empSalary > a.empSalary;
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT e.empDept, COUNT(DISTINCT e.empid) noOfEmployees
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(e1.empSalary) empSalary FROM employee e1) a ON e.empSalary > a.empSalary
GROUP BY e.empDept;
```

Comment: thanx. its comparing the avg salary of each department. but I need to compare it to whole table irrespective to the department, and then group by the total count of emp for each department.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something with a subquery, approximately as follows:

```
SELECT empID FROM TABLE t 
WHERE empSalary > (SELECT AVG(empSalary) FROM TABLE WHERE empDept = t.empDept)
```

But can also be done with a JOIN that probably performs better:

```
SELECT empID FROM TABLE t
JOIN (SELECT empDept, AVG(empSalary) AS avgSalary FROM TABLE GROUP BY empDept) averages
ON t.empDept = averages.empDept
WHERE t.empSalary > averages.avgSalary
```

EDIT: the updated question calls for something slightly different, as per first comment below. Here's a count of how many employees are above the overall average salary, by department:

```
SELECT empDept, count(empID) FROM
(SELECT empID, empDept from TABLE 
WHERE empSalary > (SELECT AVG(empSalary) FROM TABLE) aboveAverageEmployees
GROUP BY empDept
```

Comment: thanx. its comparing the avg salary of each department. but I need to compare it to whole table irrespective to the department, and then group by the total count of emp for each department

Comment: I'll revise the answer, but you should revise the question. That's not initially what you asked for.